# What does "-Dprefix" in linux do?

Tags: linux, perl, configuration

I recently installed Perl Version 5.30.0 onto my linux machine. I noticed in the install guide that when configuring Perl I had to use `-Dprefix` instead of `--prefix`. I was curious to what `-Dprefix` actually does but couldn't find any explanation online. Any information would be appreciated.

Example of `-Dprefix`:

```
./configure -Dprefix=/some/directory/location
```

What I normally use to configure a software:

```
./configure --prefix=/some/directory/location
```

Perl install guide:
https://www.cpan.org/src/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [INSTALL](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/INSTALL) file in the source tree is a guide to the build process. -D is an option to the Configure script to define a symbol in the configuration of the Perl, as described in that script's [usage text](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/6bd6308fcea3541e505651bf8e8127a4a03d22cd/Configure#L1823).

```
  -D : define symbol to have some value:
         -D symbol         symbol gets the value 'define'
         -D symbol=value   symbol gets the value 'value'
       common used examples (see INSTALL for more info):
         -Duse64bitint            use 64bit integers
         -Duse64bitall            use 64bit integers and pointers
         -Dusethreads             use thread support
         -Dinc_version_list=none  do not include older perl trees in @INC
         -DEBUGGING=none          DEBUGGING options
         -Dcc=gcc                 choose your compiler
         -Dprefix=/opt/perl5      choose your destination
```